# Spring security method annotations in controller

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to configure method secure annotations with Spring Java config, but it's not working. From trace log I can see, that @Controllers are not scanned for security annotations. That's because controller beans haven't been created yet. Controllers scanning is made from servlet config classes extending WebMvcConfigurationSupport and SecurityConfig is imported to the RootConfig. How can I set up my config to scan also controllers when I don't want to create controller beans in root config?

RootConfig:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class, PropertyPlaceholderConfig.class, DBConfig.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.models", "com.example.services" })
public class RootConfig { ...}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true, securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    ...
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        ...
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        ...
    }
}
```

Rest servlet:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.controllers.api" }, includeFilters = @Filter({ Controller.class, ControllerAdvice.class }), useDefaultFilters = false)
@Import({ PropertyPlaceholderConfig.class, RestApiDocumentationConfig.class })
public class RestApiConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {...}
```

Comment: You need to enable annotations for your web beans too. Right now `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` is applied only to your application beans and not for controllers. See [this FAQ entry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context).

Comment: Adding @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity to RestApiConfig resolved to:  `Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []`. This error appears also when I added AuthenticationManager bean configuration in ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter: `@Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
   return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }`

Comment: I tried to move controller beans scan to root and although it is scanned now and annotations are found, it's not working correctly. When I specify the annotation directly in security config, it's working as expected.

Comment: Strange. Could you show entire SecurityConfig?

Comment: I solved my problem... Both problems was in servlets configurations and were very common. I had to add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` as @Maksym suggested. And after that I needed to import corresponding class into servlet context with `@Import`. Then when I specified AuthenticationManagers in both `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` classes no error occured and it's working as expected. Thanks Maksym!